# How to alter dbunit getConnection despite it being final

Tags: java, oracle, dbunit

I am running dbunit 2.4.9. I am getting AmbiguousTableNameException after switching to a new oracle instance. The [doc](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AmbiguousTableNameException) indicates that I should put the schema name in the connection when I create it. But I can't override getConnection on DBTestCase because it is final. Should I choose a different superclass? Am I overlooking something?

Here is my testcase class.

```
public abstract class DbTestCase extends DBTestCase
{
private static boolean doOnce = false;
private Session session;

public DbTestCase() throws Exception
{
    super();
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:sid" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME, "id" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD, "xxxx_15" );
}


@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();

    if(!doOnce){
        doOnce = true;          
        BasicConfigurator.configure();          
        MyHibernateFactory.initilize();
    }

    session = MyHibernateFactory.getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}

public void tearDown() throws Exception
{  
 ...
}  

@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception
{
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream("src/dbtest/dataset.xml"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA property

```
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "SCHEMA" );
```